# Possible Performance Bottleneck in Client-Cert System

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl

My web application authenticates users via preauthentication (every request includes the client-side cert that the server uses to authenticate the request).

Setup: Apache web server, Tomcat application server, mod_jk connector

1. Client hits Apache server and selects a certificate
2. SSL handshake begins where client's browser verifies server's certificate, and server ensures that client's passed-in certificate is valid
3. Once SSL is established, server passes SSL_CLIENT_CERT to Tomcat for authentication

**EDIT:**

Addtionally, the user's client certificate is checked against a Certificate Revocation List (CRL).

Is the additional time required to download the CRL or CRL Delta and then check that the client's certificate hasn't been revoked likely time-consuming?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, but it doesn't happen as often as you might think. The server almost certainly caches the CRL and doesn't reacquire it for some interval like an hour, and your premiss that the client certificate is sent with every request isn't correct either, due to (1) HTTP keepalive and (2) SSL session caching, which keeps reusing the same SSL session for whatever period is configured at the server, maybe 10-15 minutes, maybe also an hour, maybe even a day.

Comment: Using the ActivClient (card reading software), it blinks on the task bar multiple times, i.e. for multiple HTTP requests, when I hit my web page. According to a another sw developer on my job, he said that it blinks whenever it's reading the card's credentials. Whenever the credentials are read, it adds lag (maybe 1 second or so per request).

Comment: As I understand, since I'm using Spring Security preauthentication, every request is authenticated, i.e. each request is already authenticated. Spring Security just grabs the user/principal from the HTTP request. Not all of my HTTP requests require the full client certificate, however a fair amount of them do. As a result, I believe that answer is "my code."